Multiple output DCDC flyback
I am struggling to come up with a viable design with a minimal BOM for a low power DCDC converter and would appreciate some thoughts.
The input is 24v/48v (PoE PD) with multiple output rails: 12v, 5v , 3.3v

The 24v/48v input will be switched via a jumper
The 12v output is nominal and could be 12v-36v
Ideally the 12v is isolated as it's driving 2 LM358 op-amps for 0-10v PWM circuit.
The 3.3v output I'm happy to handle with a 5v-3.3v LDO

So I'm looking to get 12v (~100mA) and 5v (~500mA) rails out. The switching regulator (MP8017) primary side SW pin can handle 105v and uses a PSR fly-buck style FB loop.
One of the only viable transformers I can find is this one from Wurth: https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/750032395.pdf

Vin: 13-59v
Out1: 5v
Out2: 3.3v
Aux: 12v

As there is no auxiliary bias required by the IC, is it possible to use the 12v aux to supply the 12v rail? (I appreciate that's not the normal use of primary side secondary coil). The 3.3v secondary output is a convenient win.
The only other off the shelf idea I can find is a Vin of 36v-57v and run the input at 24v accepting I'll get worse efficiency.
Otherwise I'm stuck with either using another primary side secondary IC like a an LM5160 to take the 24v/48v down to a 12v-36v output with a fly-buck or I need to accept no isolation on the 12v rail.
Feel like I'm going around in circles on this!

Have you considered isolated power modules instead? I can see many options here, for example. There's nothing wrong with designing the stuff from scratch but, don't get me wrong, I see too much hassle. NOTE: I don't know your size requirements but if you can't find multi-output modules you can even use multiple modules for each output, methinks.

The auxiliary winding is not intended to deliver much power and will be problematic regarding regulation.

@Andyaka Even if the primary winding is pretty tightly regulated?
